# Android app becomes unique only after getting deployed on production release

Tags: android, google-play, uniqueidentifier

Scenario: I have android build which is not ready for production release on play store but I want to reserve it's unique identifier (like com.mysuperwork.myapp). So if I release my app on internal testing track then will it become unique? or if someone else deploy the his app on play store with same identifier com.mysuperwork.myapp then I will be need to change my app identifier?